# C program: Segmentation Fault when using opendir and readdir

Tags: c, unix, directory, system-calls

I am writing a simple program that opens the current directory you are working in and prints all the contents of the directory stream, and then takes other directories through the command line and prints the contents of their stream as well.  The problem is when I type in a false directory through the command line my program fails to print "Cannot Access *directory name*" and gives me "Segmentation Fault (core dumped)"

#### This is my Main class "myls.c"

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mylsFunctions.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
        printDirectoryContents("./.");

        for( int i = 1; i<argc; i++)
                printDirectoryContents(argv[i]);
}
```

#### Here is the file with my function used in the Main "mylsFunctions.c"

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mylsFunctions.h"

void printDirectoryContents (char *directory) {
    currentDirectory = opendir(directory);
    if(currentDirectory == NULL) {                         
            printf("Cannot Access %s",directory);
            exit(-1);
    }
    while ((entry=readdir(currentDirectory)) != NULL)
            printf("%s\n",entry->d_name);
    closedir(currentDirectory);
}
```

#### Here is the Header "mylsFunctions.h"

```
#ifndef MYLSFUNCTIONS_H
#define MYLSFUNCTIONS_H

DIR *currentDirectory;
struct dirent *entry;

void printDirectoryContents(char *directory);
#endif
```

~

Comment: Do-able, but not a good coding style to define `variables` in a `.h` file like `DIR *currentDirectory; struct dirent *entry;`.  Best to put in `mylsFunctions.c` and inside `printDirectoryContents()`.

Comment: Suggest printing `printf("Cannot Access '%s'\n",directory);`.  By delimiting the name and adding `'\n'`, the dir name may print and find that the seg fault is in later code.  -- assuming code posted differs from your code.

Comment: add a check that the passed parameter is not null before using it.

Comment: Are you familiar with the `perror()` function and the `errno` global variable?  They can often give you a better idea of what's going wrong with these sorts of low level library routines.

Comment: Your main "class" is a "module", not a "class". :)

Comment: You should print the value of `char* directory` as the first statement in your `printDirectoryContents()` function to confirm what value it is working on. If this doesn't show the problem, try stepping through code with a debugger.

Comment: I got it to work finally! I had to eliminate the header file, thanks @chux.  I believe the problem was my DIR variable was a null pointer after the first function call, then during the second function call     currentDirectory    was a null pointer, which is not the same as an uninitialized pointer.  I could be wrong though